# Amazon SES with Wordpress only allows me to send to verified emails

Tags: email, wordpress, amazon-ses

Maybe I am not understanding how to use Wordpress with Amazon SES, but I am under the impression that you can setup all Wordpress emails to be sent from your Amazon SES verified email to any email address.

For example, when Wordpress sends out emails for New Registrations on the site, or when new Sites get created in a Multisite environment.  I have installed WP Mail SMTP and set Amazon SES and the Wordpress Plugin according to these instructions:  https://www.organicweb.com.au/20679/wordpress/setup-amazon-ses/

After following the instructions, any emails that get sent out to any emails that are not verified with Amazon SES do not work.  This makes no sense to me, but perhaps I need to edit the Policy that is attached to IAM users?  The email address and domain is both VERIFIED.  What else is there to do to get this working so that Wordpress can send all emails out?

This Simple Email Service is anything but simple!

Error I get is:

> SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command
>   failed Detail: Message rejected: Email address is not verified.

It is trying to verify the email address that it is sending to instead of verifying the email address that it is sending from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to contact AWS Support and request [removal from the SES Sandbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html).

Quoting from the above page (emphasis mine):

> In the sandbox, you have full access to all Amazon SES email-sending
>   methods and features so that you can test and evaluate the service;
>   however, the following restrictions are in effect:
>
> - You can only send mail to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator **and to verified email addresses and domains**.
> - You can only send mail from verified email addresses and domains.
> - You can send a maximum of 200 messages per 24-hour period.
> - Amazon SES can accept a maximum of one message from your account per second.

Comment: Awww, thank you.  Had no idea this was in Sandbox!  Cheers :)